# keras flow_from_dataframe for image segmentation (i.e. with a binary mask as label)

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Is there a way to use the method "flow_from_dataframe" from keras (https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdataframe-method) to load an image with a mask? Such that instead of y being a category, y is a path such that a binary mask gets loaded together with the image.

An example dataframe to load the data would be:

```
+---+---------------------+---------+-------------------------+
|   | img_path            | subject | mask_path               |
+---+---------------------+---------+-------------------------+
| 0 | images/DSC_4540.TIF | 4540    | masks/DSC_4540_mask.tif |
+---+---------------------+---------+-------------------------+
| 1 | images/DSC_9228.TIF | 9228    | masks/DSC_9228_mask.tif |
+---+---------------------+---------+-------------------------+
| 2 | images/DSC_6674.TIF | 6674    | masks/DSC_6674_mask.tif |
+---+---------------------+---------+-------------------------+
| 3 | images/DSC_3453.TIF | 3453    | masks/DSC_3453_mask.tif |
+---+---------------------+---------+-------------------------+
| 4 | images/DSC_6808.TIF | 6808    | masks/DSC_6808_mask.tif |
+---+---------------------+---------+-------------------------+
| 5 | images/DSC_5494.TIF | 5494    | masks/DSC_5494_mask.tif |
+---+---------------------+---------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate ImageDataGenerator for the masks and then zip it with the existing ImageDataGenerator.

Check out the third example from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe).

Comment: Hi Phillip, thanks for your answer! Yes that would work, but it is much easier to split the data into train, validation and test set in a dataframe than in directories. Is there no way to load the data from a dataframe?

Comment: Oh yeah can still use flow_from_dataframe. All of your data can be in one folder just as each generator is getting the proper filenames in their dataframes. This is because flow_from_dataframe loads specific files instead of just everything in a directory like flow_from_directory.

Comment: oh okay, but how would "flow_from_dataframe" be used without classes? Because my ground truth is a binary mask, I don't have any classes

Comment: When you zip them together like that tf reads it as an (x, y) tuple. So the second generator will be used as your training targets.